# git changing branches from a remote repo

Tags: git

I cloned a repository (from gitlab) and I think I commit a mistake.

First I cloned the repo, I made some changes and committed them in a local branch, then I realized I wanted to see another branch of the repo "another_branch" so I did

```
git checkout another_branch
```

but then I realized that some files were not there. So I did

```
git pull origin another_branch
```

and I got the files but I got the message

```
uto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

So now my repo is a mess with middle merging and uncommited changes, etc.

What did I do wrong and how can I correct this.

Answer (score 2):

After your first clone, you have changed some files.
When you tried to pull (checkout) the second branch git detect your changes and in your case, it caused a conflict.

### How to fix it?

- Few solutions here

#### Get rid of your local changes

- In case you don't need to keep your changes and you wish to discard them

```bash
# Discard local changes
git reset origin/<branch name> --hard

# Now check to see that you don't have any "new" unchanged files
git status
```

#### Keep local changes

- You are in a middle of a merge so again few options:

  - Abort the merge, commit or drop your changes

  ```bash
  # Abort the merge
  git merge --abort

  # Now you are back to square 1.
  # If you wish to keep your changes - commit them
  # if you don't need them same as above 
  git reset origin/<branch> --hard
  ```

For a more detailed answer read those posts:

- [How can I move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head) & Undo commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-can-i-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head-undo-commits/34519716#34519716)

Comment: In `git reset origin/branch name --hard`, is "branch name" a typo?

Comment: Nope - replace it with your desired branch name.